# Reading all the words in a text file in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, io

I have a large `.txt` file and I want to read all of the words inside it and print them on the screen. The first thing I did was to use `std::getline()` in this way:

```
  std::vector<std::string> words;
  std::string line;
  while(std::getline(std::cin,line)){
    words.push_back(line);
  }
```

and then I printed out all the words present in the vector `words`. The `.txt` file is passed from command line as `./a.out < myTxt.txt`.

The problem is that each component of the vector is a **whole line**, and so *I am not reading each word*.

The problem, I guess, is the spaces between words: how can I tell the code to ignore them? More specifically, is there any function that I can use in order to read each word from a `.txt` file?

**UPDATE:**

I'm trying to avoid all the commas `.`, but also `? ! ()`. I used [find_first_of()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/), but my program doesn't work. Also, I don't know how to set what are the characters I don't want to be read, i.e. `.`, `?`, `!`, and so on

```
std::vector<std::string> my_vec;
  std::string line;
  while(std::cin>>line){
    std::size_t pos = line.find_first_of("!");
    std::string line = line.substr(pos);
    my_vec.push_back(line);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

'>>' operator of type string exactly fills your requirements.

```cpp
  std::vector<std::string> words;
  std::string line;
  while (std::cin >> line) {
    words.push_back(line);
  }
```

If you need remove some noisy characters, e.g. ',','.', you can replace them with space character first.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> words;
  std::string line;
  while (getline(std::cin, line)) {
    std::transform(line.begin(), line.end(), line.begin(),
       [](char c) { return std::isalnum(c) ? c : ' '; });
    std::stringstream linestream(line);
    std::string w;
    while (linestream >> w) {
      std::cout << w << "\n";
      words.push_back(w);
    }
  }
}
```

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)

Comment: thanks, it works now! :) I've noticed that it reads also `.` and things like `""`, is there a way to tell the compiler to ignore them?

Comment: @Vefhug `operator>>` has no concept of “words”, only of whitespace-separated strings. You would have to manually strip off any punctuation that you don’t want from each string read.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I could put an `if`statement to check whether or not I have a comma `.` or a double quote `""`. I think I can use `string::find`, but I don't know what to put in the `if` body

Comment: @RemyLebeau I just updated my question with those details

Comment: @Vefhug simply erasing the unwanted characters is not going to help you split any words that are separated by them. You need to iterate through a string looking for the characters and pulling out sub-strings between them. Look at the string's `find_first_of()` and `substr()` methods.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks, I tried to follow your suggestion. I just edited my question with the code snippet, but I get the compile error `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'`. What I wrote in the edit is what you meant?

Comment: @Vefhug Almost, you are not checking the return value of `find_first_of()` for `string::npos` before calling `substr()`. I haave posted an answer showing how to use `find_first_of()`.

Answer (score 2):

The `getline` function, as it sounds, only returns a whole line. You can split each line on spaces after reading it, or you can read word by word using `operator>>`:

```
string word;
while (cin >> word){
    cout << word << "\n";
    words.push_back(word);        
}
```

Comment: I just updated my question: I'd like to avoid special characters like commas, `?`, `!` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Use `operator>>` instead of `std::getline()`. The operator will read individual whitespace-separated substrings for you.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> my_vec;
std::string s;
while (std::cin >> s){
    // use s as needed...
}
```

However, you may still end up receiving strings that have punctuation in them without any surrounding whitespace, ie `hello,world`, so you will have to manually split those strings as needed, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

std::vector<std::string> my_vec;
std::string s;
while (std::cin >> s){
    std::string::size_type start = 0, pos;
    while ((pos = s.find_first_of(".,?!()", start)) != std::string::npos){
        my_vec.push_back(s.substr(start, pos-start));
        start = s.find_first_not_of(".,?!() \t\f\r\n\v", pos+1);
    }
    if (start == 0)
        my_vec.push_back(s);
    else if (start != std::string::npos)
        my_vec.push_back(s.substr(start));
}
```